# Есть ли в Java встроенные методы для вывода числа компонентов в контейнере?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Есть ли в Java встроенные методы для вывода числа компонентов в контейнере?
К примеру, есть JFrame. В него добавлено несколько компонентов. Как узнать количество этих компонент?
На ум приходит пока только поочередная передача фокуса с проверкой индекса компонента (он у каждого компонента свой). То есть, находим максимальный индекс.
Возможно есть встроенный метод какой-то для нахождения числа компонентов в контейнере?

Comment: farame.getComponentCount();- вернет колличество компонентов.Или вопрос в поиске колличесва компонетов сортированных по типу?

Comment: Вопрос именно в количестве всех компонентов. Думал, может метод .getComponentCount() для чего то другого предназначен, так как в контейнере у меня 3 компонента, и отображается все корректно, а вызов метода .getComponentCount() выдает 1. Хотя поидее должен 3.

Comment: Вот как выглядит само приложение: [ссылка](http://c2n.me/3Aus9c8)

Comment: в списке компонентов у у JFrame компонент и есть 1(наверняка некая панель)  а уже у Панели предположим уже хранятся кнопки. etc

Comment: В том то и дело, что я сначала в JFrame добавляю меню, затем JToolBar и только потом саму панель JPanel. Поэтому должно быть 3 компонента.
Листинг программы: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547682/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-java-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-jpanel-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Вы НЕ добавляете компонент в root контейнер используя метод  add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH); просмотрите src или докумнтацию...По факту Вы вызываете защищенный метод addImpl(comp, constraints, -1); ...

Comment: Даже если я не добавляю в root контейнер через метод add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH); один компонент, то 2 остальных компонента добавляю просто через add(). Т.е. хотя бы 2 компонента добавиться должно. Или так тоже нельзя добавлять?
А каким образом тогда можно добавлять, если не через  add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH); ? Иначе, используя обычный add, панель инструментов вообще исчезает из видимости. Как в root то добавить?

Comment: Я проверил вывод вашего кода(конечно без части классов) и вывод у вас абсалютно закономерный 1 и 2 компонента...Уточню преведущий коментарий вы добавляете в root но регистрация не совсем простая...Касательно как правильно добавлять вы поступаете абсолютно верно просто поймите механизм добовления рекомендую просмотреть src...