# Как в Java передавать фокус на JPanel обычным нажатием мышки?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Как в Java передавать фокус на JPanel обычным нажатием мышки? Почему-то это не происходит автоматически. В чем может быть причина?
Листинг программы:

```
public class Test extends JFrame  implements FocusListener,  MouseMotionListener {  
    private int datePanelHeight =30;
    private ChartPanel chartPanel;
    Test() throws IOException {
        super("Графическое приложение");
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBounds(50,50,1000, 450);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);

        addToolBar();

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);
        Menu f=new Menu("Файл");
        Menu v=new Menu("Вид");
        mb.add(f);
        mb.add(v);
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(this.getContentPane().getWidth(), this.getContentPane().getHeight());
        add(chartPanel);

        chartPanel.requestFocus();
        addKeyListener(chartPanel);



        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("this.getComponentCount() = "+this.getComponentCount());
    }

    private void addToolBar(){
        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar("Панель ирструментов", JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);
        tb.add(new JButton("Кнопка"));
        tb.setFloatable(true);
        add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField("0",3);
        tf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30,100));
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        tb.add(tf);

        tb.addKeyListener(chartPanel);
        System.out.println("this.getComponentCount() = "+tb.getComponentCount());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         new FinanceMarketFrame();
    }
```

Скриншот программы:
http://clip2net.com/s/3AusFy9
Фокус с клавиатуры (используя tab) передается успешно. При нажатии мышкой по панели, фокус остается в компоненте JTextField. Почему в этом случае фокус не передается?

Comment: добавьте в обработчик щелчка по панели запрос фокуса (`requestFocusInWindow()`)

Comment: а чем отличается обычный 'requestFocus()' от 'requestFocusInWindow()' ?